# How do I alias command mathbb?

Tags: latex

I would like to alias \mathbb as simply \bb. How do I define this new command? I know how to alias mathsymbols such as:

```
\def\AND{\wedge}
```

But I am not so sure about math commands that take parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a number of options. Firstly you could

```
\let\bb\mathbb
```

which will *copy* the definition of `\mathbb` into `\bb`. This means that if the definition of `\mathbb` changes, `\bb` will remain whatever it was at the time of definition. If `\mathbb` were to take an *optional* parameter as an argument (for whatever reason), then it's more appropriate to use

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764
\LetLtxMacro{\bb}{\mathbb}
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}
```

which will insert `\mathbb` wherever you use `\bb`; more akin to an alias. This has the advantage that `\bb` will change with any changes to `\mathbb`. Also, there's no need to worry about defining `\bb` to take the same number of arguments as `\mathbb`, since TeX merely *replaces* `\bb` with `\mathbb`. That is,

```
\bb{<something>}
```

would be interpreted as

```
\mathbb{<something>}
```